# Установить кодировку в phpMyAdmin

Tags: сравнение, phpmyadmin, php, кодировка, mysql

Настраиваю базу данных через  phpMyAdmin . Как я понял, в MySQL можно указывать саму кодировку(как будет храниться), а так же правила сравнения. Но в phpMyAdmin для каждого столбца таблицы есть только надпись в которой можно менять "Сравнение", и я не как не могу найти где там можно поменять кодировку... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как через phpMyAdmin задать кодировку(а не сравнение), для столбца или таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот тут

[image]

Comment: у меня немного по другому интерфейс выглядит видимо версия более старая(5.1.55). Когда я захожу в "Операции", то там в разделе "Параметры таблицы" есть:"Переименовать таблицу в", "Комментарий к таблице", "Тип таблиц", "Сравнение", "PACK_KEYS", "CHECKSUM", "DELAY_KEY_WRITE","ROW_FORMAT". И всё... А кодировки вроде нет....

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt, сравнение - это и есть кодировка таблицы или столбца

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.